# Add Yes or No tickboxes to my site (Silverstripe)

Tags: php, content-management-system, silverstripe

I am trying to add a yes or no check boxes to one of my member forms on my Silverstripe site. I have added the boxes to the site as well as to the member section in CMS. The idea is that they should be linked eg when you tick yes on the site, the member section should be ticked yes as well. I've been trying but couldn't get the check boxes linked.

It has been a while since I touched Silverstripe, so any directions would be appreciated. Also how do I make the checkboxes to be you can only tick yes or no, at the moment you can tick both.

Here are my code so far, I will continue work on it, but it would be great if someone can point me to the right direction. Many thanks.

```
$fields = new FieldSet( ...
    new CheckboxSetField('Questions','Do you want to show this?', array('true' => 'yes', 'false' => 'no'))
...);

function doSignup($data, $form) {
$member = Member::currentUser();
...
$member->Questions = $data['Questions'];
...
}

function extraStatics() {
    return array(
        'db' => array(
           ...
          'Questions' =>"Enum('Yes,No')", 
            ...
        ), 
    );}

 public function updateCMSFields(FieldSet &$fields) {
  ...
   $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Membership', new CheckboxSetField('Questions','Do you want to show this?', array('true' => 'yes', 'false' => 'no'))); 
}
```

Comment: What version of Silverstripe are you using?

Comment: Rather than an Enum with Yes and No as options I suggest you use a Boolean that can be set to true or false. Then instead of a CheckboxSetField use a CheckboxField.

Comment: Hi 3dgoo, thanks for your reply, sorry I've been away. I'm using SS 2.4.5. Would you be able to have two tick boxes for yes and no if you use CheckboxField? If so how do I target it, some code example would be great. I tried Boolean, but it kept giving me a notice 'Undefined index: Questions', when Im not ticking the checkbox for Questions. Any help is appreciated as I am a bit stuck. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following answer is for Silverstripe 2.4.

Let's say we wanted to add a boolean checkbox to our silverstripe member object to be controlled through the CMS by any logged in administrators, and through the front end by that logged in member.

First we need to extend the Member object. In this class we add our Boolean to the database. We also add the CheckboxField to the CMS fields for members.

**MemberExtension.php**

```
class MemberExtension extends DataObjectDecorator {

    public function extraStatics() {
        return array (
            'db' => array (
                'Questions' => 'Boolean'
            )
        );
    }

    public function updateCMSFields($fields) {
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Membership', new CheckboxField('Questions', 'Do you want to show this?')); 
    }

}
```

We add the MemberExtension in our site config.

**_config.php**

```
...
Object::add_extension('Member', 'MemberExtension');
...
```

Then in our page controller we add a function to present the logged in user with a form to control this field. We also have the update function to save these changes when the form is submitted.

**OurCustomPage.php**

```
...
class OurCustomPage_Controller extends Page_Controller {
    ...
    public function MemberForm() {
        if ($member = Member::currentUser()) {
            $form = new Form (
                $this,
                'MemberForm',
                new FieldSet (
                    new CheckboxField('Questions', 'Do you want to show this?', $member->Questions)
                ),
                new FieldSet (
                        new FormAction('update', 'Update')
                )
            );

            return $form;
        }
        return false;
    }

    function update($data, $form) {
        $member = Member::currentUser();
        $member->Questions = isset($data['Questions']);
        $member->write();
        return $this->redirectBack();
    }
    ...
}
```

Note, `isset($data['Questions'])` is used to get the true/false value of the Questions checkbox. This is because if the Questions checkbox is not checked the Questions form input is not submitted. This is how `<input type="checkbox" />` works.

Lastly in our class layout template we need to add `$MemberForm`.

**OurCustomPage.ss**

```
...
$MemberForm
...
```

Comment: Hi 3dgoo, thanks so much for your help, it is working now, thank you thank you thank you, clever! Like you said it is because I didn't do isset for the checkbox data to isset($data['Questions']), I will take a note on that, thanks for the detailed explainations. Just out of interest, would you ever do a CheckboxSetField for this kind of purposes eg tick yes or no for criminal convinctions? Also what are the differences for SS 2.4 and SS3, anywhere/links I can learn it? Thanks so much for your great help, you have made my day, thank you very much!

Comment: Glad I could help. I wouldn't do a checkboxset for something like this, no. Because the value will only ever be true or false I would use a boolean. With a boolean I would use either a CheckboxField or an [OptionsetField](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-OptionsetField.html) for cases when you want the user to select either yes or no.

Comment: Silverstripe 3.1 is a much never and better version of Silverstripe. I strongly recommend using the latest version for all your projects. It's more stable, has less bugs, easier to develop for, is better supported. There are details of some of the things that have changed in the official ChangeLogs: http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/changelogs/3.0.0 and http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/3.1/changelogs/3.1.0

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate your help. Thank you:) Would you be able to show me some code if I want to use OptionsetField? I know how to show the field at the front page and CMS,you wouldn't set isset for OptionsetField, would you? $member->Questions = isset($data['Questions']); Thanks so much.

Comment: How you use it depends on you set up the OptionsetField. If you set it up like this `new OptionsetField('Questions', 'Questions', array('true' => 'Yes', false => 'No'));` you could retrievet the value something like this
`$member->Questions = isset($data['Questions']) ? $data['Questions'] : false;`. Note, I have not tested this.